# d3 axis not showing last value

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Let's say I have a linear y scale  with the domain [12,23] and 5 ticks.
The problem is that ticks are not showing as expected, meaning that the last tick, value 23 is not displayed. Instead  a dash with no value it's displayed.

Basically for me it's important to always display on the chart the first and the last value from my domain.

Also is it possible somehow to automatically add some 'padding' in my domain values ? Eg. my points that I want to draw on the chart are in this interval(12,23) for yAxis, and the first point let's say is (y=12,x=10). In this case the point will be draw over the x Axis because the y=12 is the smallest value from my y axis. So I would like somehow to automatically add some paddings in my domain so that I will never draw a point over y or x axis.

```
Here is the jsFiddle: 
    http://jsfiddle.net/z9ucLqu2/67/
```

Comment: I disagree with @LarsKotthoff's decision to close this question as duplicate. The question he linked to is not an exact duplicate of this but rather a generalization of this problem. Check [*"How to render end ticks always using d3 svg axis"*](/q/26453762) which seems to be more to the point.

Comment: @altocumulus Fair point -- I'm happy to nominate for reopening if OP agrees. I guess that would be only to close it as a duplicate of a different question though?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff The question I linked to had an answer which was rather vague on the real problem. However, I did a minor edit to include the relevant line from the JSFiddle in the answer itself. That said, yes, it is a duplicate of this other question which now has a suitable answer and should therefore be closed with the link corrected.